# JavaScript - File is instance of File, but `instanceof File` is false

Tags: javascript, file, inheritance, prototype, instanceof

I have an `<input type="file">` with a local file selected, which I would like to upload to the server as a File, not as a Blob. I'm grabbing it with jQuery (element and then `.files[0]` or `.prop('files')[0]`).

By every indication but one, the prototype of this object is File:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(file) // => File {slice: function}
file.__proto__              // => File {slice: function}
file.constructor            // => function File() { [native code] }
file.constructor.prototype  // => File {slice: function}
```

And yet:

```
file instanceof File        // => false
file instanceof Blob        // => true
```

What gives?

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob "The File interface is based on Blob, inheriting blob functionality and expanding it to support files on the user's system."

Comment: Yes, File inherits from Blob, so it's expected that `file instanceof Blob` is true, in the same way you'd expect `dog instanceof Animal` to be true. But it's very weird to find `file instanceof File` or `dog instanceof Dog` to be false.

Comment: In what browser are you testing? It works as expected in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/drzfmgba/

Comment: I should clarify that I'm not claiming this behavior is universal; in simple test cases my experience matches yours. I just can't figure out why it's as above in this specific webapp. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Works in firefox, chrome, msie by me too... Maybe your webapp overrides the `File` variable.

Comment: "Maybe your webapp overrides the File variable" That's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to by inf3rno's comment – my webapp was overwrting the `File` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter a similar problem, I save `File` in `OriginFile` variable when the page start render, but `file instanceof OriginFile` still give me `false`. But this example http://jsfiddle.net/drzfmgba/ unbelievably works in the same browser (Mac Chrome 41).

Anyway...I resolve it by `Object.prototype.toString.call(file) === '[object File]'`.